# how to export excel if there is a relation table?, I use laravel excel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database, view

line of code to get attendance database

```
public function collection()
{
    return Attendance::all();
}
```

if I use collection, only export on a database in below image
[Database Attendance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnH8H.png)

here is the user relation database [Database User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSaI7.png)

which I hope can display data like the following display [Show Attendance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18dEY.png)

what I know is that it only uses SQL but I'm confused to apply it to Laravel like the following sql code:

```
SELECT attendances.id, users.name, IF(status=0, 'Check In','Check Out') AS status, 
       attendances.created_at, attendances.update_at
FROM attendances
INNER JOIN users ON attendances.user_id = users.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using `Maatwebsite\Excel` package, you can do like below base on what you had and another example :

First example will cover `hasMany` and the second `belongsTo`.

Controller:

```
return Excel::download(new OffersExport, 'offers.xlsx');
```

Attendance:

```
    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Offers::class);
    }
```

OffersExport:

```
    public function collection()
    {
        // this is an example, not exactly like your database structure 
        return Attendance::with('offers')->all();
    }

    // Here you can manipulate data to export

    public function map($row): array
    {
        // row will be the attendance and offers will be the relationship
        $offers = array();
        foreach ($row->offers as $offer) {
            $offers[] = $offer->name.' : '.$offer->price;
        }


        return [
            $row->ID, // attendance->id
            $row->created_at, // attendance->created_at
            implode(" | ",$offers) // list of offers separated with | base on above logic
        ];
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        // Exported Excel Headers, in order, which you should match them base on
        // manipulated data in above
        return [
            'id',
            'created_at',
            'offers'
        ];
    }
 
    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        // Here you can apply some customization to final export file, for example
        // setRightToLeft, apply RTL to sheet.
        return [
            AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->setRightToLeft(true);
            },
        ];
    }
```

So basically as far as i see, you can simply replace offers with users like below :

Attendance Model :

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

```
    public function collection()
    {
        // this is an example, not exactly like your database structure 
        return Attendance::all();
    }

    public function map($row): array
    {

        return [
            $row->id, // attendance id
            $row->status, // attendance status
            $row->user->name, // attendance belongs to user
        ];
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'id',
            'status',
            'user'
        ];
    }
```

Comment: After I am done with an export I would like to flag the rows that have been exported so they won't be exported the next time, I have a boolean column for this in the database('is_exported'). How can update this column for every row that's been exported?